# не сбрасывать скрипт после обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть сайт на тех домене [applem5q.beget.tech](http://applem5q.beget.tech/) . На главной странице находится меню с перечнем услуг. Ситуация: заходишь, выбираешь свой телефон (к примеру айфон 5), выбираешь услугу для него и клацаешь по ней, после чего нажимая кнопку назад возвращаешься на главную страницу. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы скрипт не сбрасывался и оставался открытым перечень услуг для айфона 5, а не сбрасывалось обратно на 3gs?

Comment: Если вы писали его сами, то при выборе телефона меняйте хистори браузера, чтобы вернувшись назад попадали на туже страницу а не на ее корень.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью Cookie. В куки записываешь выбранный телефон в переменную например selectPhone. На главной проверяешь selectPhone. Cookie, если в selectPhone, есть выводишь его меню.

Comment: так же подойдет `localStorage`

Comment: Вы сможете это реализовать за вознаграждение?